# calling even a simple c function in c# produces System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, c

so I have got the following functions written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Dll   __declspec( dllexport )

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}

Dll void printHelp() 
{
    printf("Halcyon compiler help:\n");
    printf("   -compile [File] - Compiles file to executable\n");
    printf("   -convert [File] - Converts file to IL. File's will be written down here\n");
    printf("   -result [Text] - how does given line look in IL\n");
    return;
}

Dll void printInfoHelp() 
{
    printf("-info\n");
    printf("   classes - Prints all classes\n");
    printf("   elements - Prints currently loaded elements\n");
    printf("   version - Prints current version of SlashButter\n");
    return;
}
```

And this is my C# code importing the functions:

```
[DllImport(@"Utils.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void printHelp();
[DllImport(@"Utils.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void printInfoHelp();
```

However when I call `printHelp()` or `printInfoHelp()` I get `System.AccessViolationExcepion`. I have looked up many similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but none seemed to help me. I am compiling x86, visual studio hosting process disabled, unsafe code allowed, `CallingConvention` added, but still it is to no avail.
Is there something I am doing wrong? It is really frustrating.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

EDIT: I accidentally didn't paste the whole file here. Added the #include lines.

Comment: Are you compiling as C or C++? If you are compiling as C++ you need to enclose the function with `extern "C" {`  <function> `}` to prevent C++ name mangling. Also, since you are creating a DLL you don't need a `main`.

Comment: I am compiling C with Tiny C Compiler. TCC seems to require main in every assembly

Comment: Can you post your calling via your c# source. I am working with an emulator that requires an external DLL (C). I am using visual studio to build - I have the [STAThreadAttribute] above my main function (C#) and I also have 'Enable native code debugging'... I realize you are using a different development system - but regarding what you have done so far - that's looking good. Hope this might help.

Comment: DLL produced with Visual C++ do not have an undersocre prefix appended to the exported symbols. Tiny C probably add these prefix like GCC anbd BCC and C# from Microsoft may expect no undescore to be Visual C++ compatible. You may try `public static extern void _printHelp();` it may works.